# Raspbian breaks after removing obsolete packages

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, packages

I would like to remove obsolete packages from my Raspberry Pi 2, so, I removed all the extra source packages of my Raspbian Jessie, and left only the [official Raspbian mirrors](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository):

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

(I also included mirrordetector sources)

Then, I ran the command (after `apt-get update`)

```
apt-show-versions | grep -i "no available version"
```

which showed me the following packages to be obsolete:

```
gcc-4.5-base:armhf 4.5.3-12+rpi1 installed: No available version in archive
libboost-iostreams1.46.1:armhf 1.46.1-8 installed: No available version in archive
libboost-iostreams1.48.0:armhf 1.48.0-3 installed: No available version in archive
libdb5.1:armhf 5.1.29-5 installed: No available version in archive
libdrm-amdgpu1:armhf 2.4.71-1+rpi1 installed: No available version in archive
libdrm-tegra0:armhf 2.4.71-1+rpi1 installed: No available version in archive
libgcrypt11:armhf 1.5.0-5+deb7u3 installed: No available version in archive
libgnutls26:armhf 2.12.20-8+deb7u3 installed: No available version in archive
libllvm3.9:armhf 1:3.9-4 installed: No available version in archive
libprocps0:armhf 1:3.3.3-3 installed: No available version in archive
libraspberrypi-bin:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
libraspberrypi-dev:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
libraspberrypi-doc:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
libraspberrypi0:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
libwayland-bin:armhf 1.11.0-2 installed: No available version in archive
minecraft-pi:armhf 0.1.1-4 installed: No available version in archive
omxplayer:armhf 0.3.7~git20160923~dfea8c9 installed: No available version in archive
penguinspuzzle:armhf 20120902-1 installed: No available version in archive
pypy-upstream:all 4.0.1+dfsg-1+rpi1 installed: No available version in archive
python-minecraftpi:armhf 0.1.1-4 installed: No available version in archive
python-picamera:armhf 1.12 installed: No available version in archive
python-pifacecommon:all 4.2.1-1 installed: No available version in archive
python-pifacedigitalio:all 3.1.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
python-rpi.gpio:armhf 0.6.3~jessie-1 installed: No available version in archive
python3-minecraftpi:armhf 0.1.1-4 installed: No available version in archive
python3-picamera:armhf 1.12 installed: No available version in archive
python3-pifacecommon:all 4.2.1-1 installed: No available version in archive
python3-pifacedigital-scratch-handler:all 2.0.5-1 installed: No available version in archive
python3-pifacedigitalio:all 3.1.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
raspberrypi-artwork:all 20150921 installed: No available version in archive
raspberrypi-bootloader:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
raspberrypi-kernel:armhf 1.20161215-1 installed: No available version in archive
raspi-config:all 20161207 installed: No available version in archive
raspi-copies-and-fills:armhf 0.5-1 installed: No available version in archive
rpi-update:all 20140705 installed: No available version in archive
```

I removed them all, and that broke my Debian Jessie! It won't boot anymore, and it won't even start with HDMI (even if I enable hotplug).

Luckily, I kept an image of the SD card, so I restored the image, tried again, and verified that this is the cause. Obviously I'm removing some important packages, so my question is:

**So my question is:** What are the correct sources of these packages that I have to keep for Debian Jessie? And how can I clean up obsolete packages without breaking my Raspbian?

Please ask if you require additional details.

Comment: Did you really think you would get away with removing `raspberrypi-bootloader` and `raspberrypi-kernel`? Don't those names sound kind of important?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev lol... didn't know how essential that is. I thought RPi is just like normal computers, and worst-case would be some kind of easy recovery. It's disappointing though that these libraries are not available for Debian Stretch.

Comment: Those are not libraries but the bootloader and Linux kernel, respectively. AFAIK you can't run that kernel directly with Stretch, but you can get lots of Stretch updates via `jessie-backports`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Actually it did work with stretch. But some drivers weren't working properly as I heard, such as CEC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the sources I mentioned in my question are not sufficient. There is this following repos that is important as it contains hardware bindings (apparently) of raspberry pi. The library names suggest that.

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
```

Btw, this repos doesn't have bindings for Debian Stretch, although the primary bindings may work there. Debian Stretch was the reason why I started this fiasco.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-show-versions` is not a standard tool, and the way that you're using it isn't reporting obsolete files, just those that aren't in the repo or in your cache. If you want to save space, `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get clean` will clean up superfluous installed packages and empty your download cache without breaking your system.

Comment: Sir, I think your answer is incorrect. First, if you're concerned about standard tools, then you have to know that aptitude provides the same result with `aptitude search '~o'`. If you're running a high security Linux system, you should do this test very frequently. Obsolete packages create a huge risk for Linux systems because they don't get security updates. If you're concerned about security, I suggest you research a little more on this.

Comment: Well, you didn't tell us that you were trying to upgrade to stretch and that you'd removed the raspberrypi.org hardware repo, the actual cause of your problems. apt-show-versions run as a user returns far too many packages (for me) to be a reliable indicator of what's obsolete.